# Ruby: Finding most recently modified file

Tags: ruby, idioms

What's an idiomatic way to find the most recently modified file within a directory?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
Dir.glob("*").max_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. Thank you.

Comment: Dir.glob("/path/to/search/**/*.*").max_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}

Comment: @WiredIn 's comment reduces the results to files which have a period in them (only files with an extension). See following for including 'hidden' dotfiles... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385795/ruby-list-directory-with-dir-including-dotfiles-but-not-and

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there really is an idiom for this. I would do

```
Dir["*"].sort_by { |file_name| File.stat(file_name).mtime }
```

#### Edit

Seeing how three people gave more or less the same answer at the same time. This must be it.

Comment: Downvoted because this didn't answer the OP's question (returns sorted list of times instead of the most recent one). It's also less concise than the other two answers.

Comment: You can do better obviously. Why didn't you answer it then?

Answer (score 3):

```
Dir["*"].sort { |a,b| File.mtime(a) <=> File.mtime(b) }.last
```

This is not recursive.