# How to list directory contents including dotfiles but not . and ..?

Tags: ruby, file, directory, glob, dotfiles

How do I get `Dir['*']` to include dotfiles, e.g., `.gitignore`, but not `.` and `..`?

I.e., is there a better way to do:

```
`ls -A`.split "\n"
```

perhaps with `Dir`? The following solutions are close but both include `.` & `..`:

```
Dir.glob('*', File::FNM_DOTMATCH)
Dir['{.*,*}']
```

So, the following works:

```
Dir.glob('*', File::FNM_DOTMATCH) - ['.', '..']
```

But, is there still a better way to do this?

I'm wondering this to fix line 9 of a [Meteor Homebrew Formula](https://gist.github.com/3072321#file_meteor.rb).

Comment: You've essentially edited your answer with the solution between me starting to answer and answering… `:P`

Comment: What about `Dir.glob(“{*,.*}”)`?

Comment: @nemesv cool. I just noticed that myself from reading the [Dir::glob Ruby Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) and added it to my question. It also includes the `.` & `..` entries.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall `ls -A` excludes `.` & `..` on OS X. Perhaps, you're thinking of `ls -a`?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale I have `ls` aliased to `ls -aFh` and didn't do `\ls -A` …whoops. Realized it after the fact though and deleted the (wrong) comment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't with [`Dir[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D), but you can with [`Dir.glob`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-glob), which `Dir[]` calls:

```
Dir.glob("*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH)
```

You can get rid of the `.` & `..` easily:

```
Dir.glob("*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH).tap { |a| a.shift(2) }
```

But I think it’s probably best to stick with your original way:

```
Dir.glob("*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH) - %w[. ..]
```

(among other ways)

However, if you don’t require a more sophisticated glob than `*`, [`Dir#children`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-children) may be all you need (can always further [`filter`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-filter)/[`grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) the results if more filtering is needed):

```
Dir.children('.')
```

Comment: Better than `tap...` might be `reject { |a| a =~ /^\.{1,2}$/ }`, which is more informative and also does not depend upon the order of the directory entries.

Comment: @WayneConrad Yea I just did it quickly as the OP edited their question in rapid-fire mode. the best way is probably the array difference `... - %w[. ..]`. The regex needed for the reject seems too dense for what is actually somewhat simple (not like my code was much clearer about the goal though `:P`)

Comment: `tap` is a pretty cool method though. :) But, good point, I'll stick with array difference for now. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Matt - Oh, Array difference is way better than `reject`.

Comment: You can also reject `!File.file?( x )` as a way to reject `.` and `..` if you don't mind ignoring directories.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a shorter version:

```
Dir['{.[^\.]*,*}']
```

Comment: This wouldn't match a file such as `..foobar`.

Comment: Why would you want to match `..foobar`? .DOT files/folders are normal part of a file system listings (especially on linux/mac which use extFS), ..foobar would be an unlikely edgecase

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it to find all files in a directory including hidden files and remove `.git/`, `.`, `..`, and directories:

```rb
      files = Dir.glob("#{ARGV.first}/**/*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH)
      files = files.grep_v(/\/.git\//).grep_v(/\/\.$/).grep_v(/\/\.\.$/)
      files = files.select { |file| File.file?(file) }
```